# Add pattern to a png image (in canvas) with FabricJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to add pattern background to a png image that i have added into canvas. I used `setPatternFill` method provided by fabric js. But it's not working.

How ever, when i tried to add pattern to a rectange, it worked.

So what am i doing wrong?

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QT3pa/28/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the issue on github (https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/2112), I think it is not possible yet because the author marked it as a possible feature. 
I needed the same functionality. So I thought to share with you what I found.

By the way I used the lirary canvas-masking to mask images. Here is the link https://github.com/codepo8/canvas-masking , in case anyone needs it.